# Advanced indent settings in Visual Studio

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013, indentation

I'm using VS2013 and I'd like to change indentation. However, Visual's settings aren't enough for me. I'd like it to auto indent it like this:

```
int function()
{
    int a=1;
    while (a)
        {
            if(a>0)
                {
                    a=0;
                    return;
                }
        }

}
```

Are there any plugins, or anything like this to help me with indentation?